# Ciphers in SCHANNEL not mapping to protocol

Tags: windows, encryption, schannel

I have the following cipher suites set trough policy:

[image: screen from powershell]

As per this list (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-server-2022) I had expected the two "unresolved" ciphers to map to 771, TLS1.2.

Any advice as to why that is not happening?